# Firebase Observer not Removed in Swift

Tags: swift, firebase

Top of class:

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
var handler:FIRDatabaseHandle!
```

From view coming on screen:

```
self.handler = self.ref.child("Requests").observe(.value, with: {(snapshot) in
```

Finally:

```
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool)
{
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)

    self.ref.removeObserver(withHandle: self.handler)
    self.ref.removeAllObservers()
}
```

Unfortunately when the database is changed in another view the observer in the VC above is still called.  I understand I should not need both removes but I am trying everything.  From breakpoints I can see that the remove code is firing and I can also see that the observer is being called just once.

What am I missing in removing the observer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're removing the observer from the wrong reference.

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Requests")
```

Try making this your ref instead and then:

```
self.handler = self.ref.observe(...
```

Comment: Pure gold Callam, thank you!  I'll accept the answer as soon as the system lets me.